# Inject Client-Ids for fluent server change

Tags: socket.io

I am currently redirecting the socket io through a custom proxy. The server it actually gets send to changes from time to time. The "new" server is notfied that a client will connect/swap to it before it connects/swaps. The only issue is that this leads to the client timing out and reconnecting, which works, but takes 2 seconds that I dont want to client to wait on switch. I do not want the client to know that the server change so somehow i have to make the server to add the upcomming client/socket id to its internal list.
How could I achieve this?

Ive looked at the socket.io-adapter, but I wasn't sure if that is only for rooms/or if there is an easier way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears using the adapter would fix it. Rather than adding my own I just ended up accessing the default namespace and doing a 'addAll' to add the client.

```
io.nsps["/"].adapter.addAll(socketId, new Set<Room>([socketId]));
```